# MVC 3 post model and additional parameter to HttpPost action method using Ajax form

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-ajax

Using ASP.NET MVC 3 and Razor, I have a strongly typed view against `MyViewModel` class. Within the view I have an AJAX form that consists of a group of radio buttons. Below it, I have a normal HTML form that collects data for `MyViewModel`. Depending on which radio button is selected in the AJAX form, I want to update the HTML form with one set of default values or another. In the AJAX form, I'm trying to post two pieces of data: 1) a value that represents the option chosen (basedon the radio button `value` parameter), and 2) the `Model` from the view. I want the controller action to update the model based on the option received, and then return a partial view with the updated model object as parameter. How do I do this? Here's the code for the AJAX form for my attempt:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("MyAction", "MyController",
        new AjaxOptions {
            HttpMethod = "POST",
            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
            UpdateTargetId = "createForm"
        })) 
{
    <div id="formOptions">
        @foreach (Option op in Model.GetOptions()) {
            <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.RadioButton("option", op.OptionType, false, new { @id = op.ID, @name = op.ID, @title = @op.Description, @onfocus = "javascript:$(this).closest('form').find(':submit').first().click()" })
            <label for="@op.ID">@op.Name</label>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
    @Html.Hidden("model", Model)
    <input type="submit" value="Select" style="display:none;" />
}
```

My problem is that the `model` parameter in the HttPost action method is null.  However, the `option` parameter seems to get passed correctly. I'm not sure if I'm using the `Html.Hidden` input in a way it's not supposed to be used or what the problem is. I can post more code if needed.

This is my first attempt at doing something like this, so after reading a lot of (seemingly) similar questions I still cannot decipher the solution for what I want to do. I see a lot of different things, like JSON encoding, using JQuery, etc., but I'm not sure if I need those things, or if I can accomplish this using MVC features (I'd rather not recode things that are already built into MVC 3). If anyone can point me in the right direction or possibly give a little code example, it would be appreciated. And, given what my end goal is, if there's a better way to asynchronously update a form based on option controls, I'd be very interested to hear about it. Thanks!

EDIT:

I also noticed that the request using HttpPost does not make it to the controller, but a HttpGet does. Anyone out there? This is driving me nuts!

ADDED CONTROLLER METHOD:

```
public PartialViewResult CreateForm(OptionType opType, MyViewModel model) {
    model.ApplyOptionValues(opType);
    return PartialView("_CreateForm", model);
}
```

Comment: Can you add the method signature you're trying to post to please?

Answer (score 0):

I would not post the entire model back to the controller which you are attempting to do with `@Html.Hidden("model", Model)`  simply place the specific items you need in the form with names/types that match your controller.  You can use the selected radio button's value as well as a hidden input's values to pass identifying information to the controller and perform whatever logic you need there.

That being said, I think the best solution going forward would be to use some javascript framework like JQuery to handle all AJAX requests.  Asp.net MVC makes it really easy to do simple operations with the built in pieces, but once you need to perform more complicated operations, it definitely falls short.  You end up putting in more effort to work within the limitations than if you just used the correct tool (JQuery).

Make sure that you annotate your POST action methods with `[HttpPost]`  to differentiate from GET methods.

Also use a detailed web debugger to examine exactly what is being sent to your application.  I like Fiddler, which is extremely popular.
http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

Comment: Thanks for the JQuery suggestion. I had read similar comments elsewhere, so I may go that route.

Answer (score 0):

I would agree with Mattbo: posting the whole model round in a circle is unnecessary overhead. You don't say why you are but I suspect it's so you can compare 'old' and 'new' values. Given the model originates in the controller, you could include a unique identifier for the model (e.g. GUID) in the ViewModel, put that in a hidden field to include in your POST data, then on the return POST your 'new' data will be auto mapped to the strongly typed ViewModel. You can then re-get the original model and do whatever you need to with them both.

Dealing with the AJAX form is a separate issue/form then: you have your radio buttons which fill out default values in the (view model) form (including a hidden field to record which radio was selected), the user fills out the other data and the whole of the (non ajax) form gets posted to the MyController.MyAction method and the default binders will automatically map the form values to the MyViewModel, if they follow the right naming convention. So the AJAX has nothing to do with the form that is actually posted. Alternatively you could do the whole thing with AJAX as Mattbo also suggests.

[Aside] Forgive me if you already know but you can use the razor Html helpers to create your fields like:

```
@Html.EditorForModel()
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.[field name])
```

In the Controller you would create the actions like:
    public ActionResult MyAction()
    {
      MyViewModel
    }

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyAction(MyViewModel myModel)
```

Comment: Regarding posting the whole model, the reason is that the model contains some properties that will not be affected by the option chosen. So, if a user entered data for those unaffected fields, then selected a different option, the refreshed form (using a brand new model) would replace the data that should be independent of the option chosen with default values, and the user would have to re-enter that data. Does that make sense?